# How to get update confirmation in mongodb nodejs driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb npm module to connect to my mongo database using nodejs.

My simple use case is that I need to update a document in a collection which may or may not exist.

So if the document exists I should be able to update it and send a confirmation in my api response.

If the document does not exists I should respond with an appropriate message that document doesn't exists.

Basically a very simple use case.

This is how I am updating:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect(url, function(conn_err, db) {
    if (conn_err) {
        console.log("Error connecting to mongodb server!!");
        console.error(conn_err);
    } else {
        console.log("Connected to mongodb server!!");
        var collection = db.collection("test");

        collection.updateOne(query, {"$set": data}, {w: "majority"}, function (err, result) {
            console.error(err);
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
});
```

Now in `result` in callback I get an object containing many things but mainly:

```
result: { ok: 1, nModified: 1, n: 1 }
...
matchedCount: 1,
modifiedCount: 1,   
upsertedId: null,
upsertedCount: 0
```

Now this is where my trouble starts.

1) If a document exists and it is updated I get:

```
result: { ok: 1, nModified: 1, n: 1 },
...
matchedCount: 1,
modifiedCount: 1,   
upsertedId: null,
upsertedCount: 0
```

2) If a document exists but is not updated (because the field values in `$set` are already same as those in the db) I get:

```
result: { ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 1 },
...
matchedCount: 1,
modifiedCount: 0,   
upsertedId: null,
upsertedCount: 0
```

3) But if a document doesn't exists I get:

```
result: { ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 1 },
...
matchedCount: 1,
modifiedCount: 0,   
upsertedId: null,
upsertedCount: 0
```

Basically how do I differentiate between case 2) and 3)?
I don't want to do multiple queries for each update.

Can anyone please advice?

**Note:**
mongodb v3.0.7,
nodejs v4.2.2,
mongodb npm module v2.0.x

Answer (score -2):

Re-read the `$set` documentation  https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/set/  It specifically says it will replace what is there. So it doesn't care if a document exists or not that's why it doesn't return the error. you need additional operators to reject the query if it exists and is the same.

**edit/update to below comment**

You have to trigger the error in order to know if the DB as the collection already and if it's up to date. So an additional operator is required to check if the collection found already has the updated information.
MongoDB uses operators represented with `$` so `$gt or $lt or $nor` (greater than , less than, Select everything but this) there's more but i'll let you explore the possibilities. https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/nor/

**this line** needs to trigger the error based on your expressions and operators. when you get that working don't just throw the error allow the program to continue to the next because this error isn't meant to break (throw) on that error it's only there to tell you hey the DB has this and it's updated, and on error will let you know nothing was done.

`collection.updateOne(query, {"$set": data},{w: "majority"},function (err,result){ console.error(err);console.log(result); });`

Comment: Can u plz elaborate? Which error and which additional operators do you mean?

Comment: `collection.updateOne(query, {"$set": data},{w: "majority"},function (err,result){ console.error(err);console.log(result); });`